# Odd colours/saturation/darkness

Tags: desktop

Recently I've updated to the kernel version 4.13.3, which caused me the problem of black screen at login and the inability to log into the OS. After fixing that, I found myself with strange fonts, a kind of saturation of the colors and an overall darkness to the screen even with brightness at 100%. I've managed to solve the terminal fonts with a global gsettings reset, however this unusual darkness remains, and I've got no idea how to fix it.

I've tried different kernel versions, but nothing changed. [image]

[image]

I don't know how much you can see in the pictures, but for me with an app opened, the widget on top is very black, so everything greyed out is black.

Comment: Did you try reverting back to the original kernel? Things get buggy when loading in newer kernels.

Comment: I did, but nothing changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too much contrast/exposure? (I think)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13438/too-much-contrast-exposure-i-think)