# Too much contrast/exposure? (I think)

Tags: updates, display, graphics, laptop

So after the last update a few days ago I noticed that everything just had too much contrast (or exposure, I'm not sure), the text also looks weird and it's been a pain to look at. What do you guys think is it?

[image: PDF and Files]

It used to look like this:
[image]

Comment: I still have this problem and haven't found a solution yet. The gamma change has only been applied to eOS native apps.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Gala, see [issue Tracker](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/100).

Answer (score 0):

I few people have reported this issue recently. Have you tried using xrandr to adjust your gamma settings? If not try this...

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --gamma 0.9:0.9:0.9
```

Note: eDP-1 is my monitor. Yours might be different. So substitute for whatever your monitor is.

You might have to play around with the settings to get it right. You'll also need to add this command to your start up. So that the settings will stick.

Answer (score 0):

I once installed Intel drivers in a desperate attempt to improve my battery life (it didn't work, by the way). Apparently that seems to be related.

Downgrading to the original drivers solved the problem. It took me a while to find the right way to do it:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/531540/how-to-safely-remove-proprietary-intel-driver